# RTSP with VLC-QT (Qt4): libvlc: video output creation failed

Tags: qt, qt4, rtsp, vlc-qt

I wrote a Qt4 widget to stream network video using vlc-qt library. Of course it works on my PC but I get the following errors when I try and run my application on the target machine (Deb 8):

```
libvlc: video output creation failed
libvlc: failed to create video output
```

then waits for a while and starts pushing:

```
libvlc: cannot estimate delay: Input/output error
```

Program does not crash, it just keeps pushing above warnings. I can stream from the same address using vlc installed on that pc (`vlc rtsp://url`), thus, i do not think it is about vlc plugins on the target pc.

Comment: Unsure what you mean above but it is probably about starting the program remote via the terminal? If so, not gonna work then.

Comment: I am running application from openbox/xterm, not from terminal remotely. GUI does appear, sorry if it was not so clear. Qt gui is visible but stream fails to start, giving the errors i mentioned.

Comment: Then that VM capabilities probably not sufficient for the video.

Comment: Always share full logs. And versions of libvlc for both the working and not working cases

Comment: @mfkl libvlc version for target machine is: 2.2.7 and for development PC it is 3.0.9.2. I could not find any logs.

Comment: those versions potentially have millions of different lines of code between them. Use the same version everywhere please